# how to insert/update in laravel with column name as array

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent, sql-insert

i have 2 type of code use laravel eloquent to insert data to database. but the problem is laravel cant use the column name as array. here its the code

```
//manual
$insert = new AlarmActive;
$insert->$primaryKey = $value[$primaryIndex];
$insert->Specific_problem = $value[1];  
$insert->Managed_object = $value[2];    

$insert->save(); 

//with for
$insert = new AlarmActive;
for($i=0; $i<count($column); $i++){
    $insert->$column[$i] = $value[$i];
}
$insert->save();
```

the first code with tag //manual is doing fine and can input to database. but when i try with for (//with for) laravel say it to convertion the array to string. my $column[$i] values is the database column name and i can echo it.

so my question how to make the second code run.

EDIT
here it my code to fill $column variable

```
 function inputAlarmActive($filenamewithoutex)
    {
        $line = Storage::get( 'public/'.$filenamewithoutex[0].'/show_alarm_active.log' );;
        $fLine = explode("\n", $line);
        $size = count($fLine);
        $data = array();
        $arr_data;
        $temp;
        $column;//Kolom tabel database
        $value;//Nilai Kolom
        $batas = "Appl. addl. info";
        $tabel = "show_alarm_active";
        $primaryKey ="Alarm_ID";
        $primaryIndex =0;


    for ($i=0; $i < $size; $i++) {
        if (strpos($fLine[$i], " :") !==false) {
            $temp[] = $fLine[$i];
        }
    }
    $this->ArrayData($temp, $batas, $tabel,$primaryKey,$primaryIndex);
}

function ArrayData($temp, $batas, $tabel, $primaryKey, $primaryIndex)
{
    global $fLine, $size,$data;
    for ($i=0; $i < count($temp) ; $i++) {
        $data = explode(":", $temp[$i]);
        $kolom = trim($data[0], " ");
        $kolomdot = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-\\ ]/', '', $kolom);

        if(strpos($kolomdot, ' ')){
            $column[]=str_replace(' ', '_', $kolomdot);
        }
        else{
            $column[]=str_replace('-', '_', $kolomdot);   
        }
        $value[]=$data[1];

        if (strpos($temp[$i], $batas)!==false) {
            $this->InsertData($column, $value, $tabel,$primaryKey, $primaryIndex);
            unset($column);
            unset($value);
        }
    }
}
```

first function "input alarm active" use to read the file with parameter the name of the folder. in this function im explode ":" to get data, the left of ":" will be the column, and the right will be the value.

second function is arraydata to fill the column array variable and fill value array variable.

third class is insert data, the code to insert to database.

here its the output of

```
for($i=0; $i<count($column); $i++){
echo $column[$i]." : ".$value[$i]."<br>";
```

}

[image: Output $column and $value]

here its the dd() output of $column

```
array:14 [▼
  0 => "Alarm_ID"
  1 => "Specific_problem"
  2 => "Managed_object"
  3 => "Severity"
  4 => "Cleared"
  5 => "Clearing"
  6 => "Acknowledged"
  7 => "Ack_user_ID"
  8 => "Ack_time"
  9 => "Alarm_time"
  10 => "Event_type"
  11 => "Application"
  12 => "Identif_appl_addl_info"
  13 => "Appl_addl_info"
]
```

here the dd() of $value

```
  array:14 [▼
  0 => " 103736\r"
  1 => " 70025 - POSSIBLE SECURITY THREAT IN NETWORK ELEMENT\r"
  2 => " fsFragmentId=PamAlarmThrower,fsFragmentId=security,fsClusterId=clusterRoot\r"
  3 => " 4 (minor)\r"
  4 => " no\r"
  5 => " manual\r"
  6 => " no\r"
  7 => " N/A\r"
  8 => " N/A\r"
  9 => " 2017-06-03 08"
  10 => " x4 (quality of service)\r"
  11 => " fsFragmentId=PamAlarmThrower,fsFragmentId=security,fsClusterId=clusterRoot\r"
  12 => " \r"
  13 => " \r"
]
```

Comment: could you show the code that fills the `$column` variable?

Comment: show the output of `$column` and `$value` array

Comment: could you do a `dd($column)` and show us the output?

Comment: @Quezler im already edit it.

Comment: @PankajMakwana im already show the output

Comment: @Quezler edit: show dd()

Comment: i'm suspecting `  2 => "Managed_object" ` could be an array/object, could you show a `dd` of `$value` as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
$insert->setAttribute($columns[$i], $values[$i]);
```

If you check the `__call()` and `__get()`/`__set()` in the base [Model-class](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php) this is what's happening there and the method itself seems to be public according to [the trait that implements it](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php).

Comment: i got 2/2) QueryException

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '__More__Severity' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `show_alarm_active` (`Alarm_ID`, `Specific_problem`, `Managed_object`, `__More__Severity`, `Cleared`, `Clearing`, `Acknowledged`, `Ack_user_ID`, `Ack_time`, `Alarm_time`, `Event_type`, `Application`, `Identif_appl_addl_info`, `Appl_addl_info`) values ( 109248 bla bla bla..

Comment: Is the name `__More__Severity` really the name of the attribute/field? Maybe you have to sanitize the values in `$column` e.g. remove the underscores?

Comment: i want to ask, how to make condition to avoid duplicate data in primary key

Comment: I think the easiest solution for you would be to call a `::find($value[$primaryKeyIndex])` before changing the data and then check if something was found or not and then do whatever you want (error, change key, etc.). I would recommend asking a new question for this, as this could easily become a more complex answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$insert->{$column[$i]} = $value[$i];
```

Comment: i got 2/2) QueryException SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '__More__Severity' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into show_alarm_active (Alarm_ID, Specific_problem, Managed_object, __More__Severity, Cleared, Clearing, Acknowledged, Ack_user_ID, Ack_time, Alarm_time, Event_type, Application, Identif_appl_addl_info, Appl_addl_info) values ( 109248 bla bla bla..

Comment: validate your $column array. There must be only array of columns for your table. Unknown column '__More__Severity'  is  very clear error.